# Experimental slideshow with 3 images at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, cross-fade

I'm searching for a smart solution to create a slideshow with 3 crossfading images.

The active image should be

1. fade in to 80% opacity in three seconds
2. stay for 1 second
3. fade out in 3 seconds to 0% opacity

All images should do the same but with an offset in time by 2 seconds. As result all 3 images should be showed at the same time.

```
<div id="cycler">
    <img class="active" src="http://lorempixel.com/720/576/cats/" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/720/576/sports/" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/720/576/food/" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/720/576/fashion/" alt="" />
</div>
```

Here is my starting [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y8yL4m2/1/)

--

Here is the final code - http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9c32wkuk/14/ - 
works as expected. 
Thanks for your ideas guest271314!

Comment: If possible, can post pieces have tried ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting jsfiddle. When read original post , interpreted "As result all 3 images should be showed at the same time." literally , .e.g., a column with images fading from top to bottom in sequence - rather than "stacked" from previous to next, minimally visible through `zIndex` layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css

```
#cycler img {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0.0;
}
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $.fx.interval = 0;
    (function cycleImages(n, cycler) {
        cycler.eq(n)         
           .fadeTo(3000, 0.8, function () {
            n = n < cycler.length - 1 ? ++n : 0;
            cycleImages(n, cycler) && $(this).delay(2000, "fx")
        }).fadeTo(3000, 0.055);          
    }(0, $('#cycler img')));
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9c32wkuk/15/